# How to remove the trailing space at the end of a line when using fprintf in c++

Tags: c++, printf, whitespace, iomanip

I am trying to write to file a set of integer from 1 to 640 (with fixed width=8) without use of newline. When i scroll across each row (take row1), there is a space left (for fixed width=8) at the end of the row as shown in the image. When the cursor is moved from beginning of one integer to that of the next, the column value  increments by 8.

**I need the cursor to jump to the next row immediately after the last integer in that row (i.e 16 in first row) has been crossed (i.e without extra space as in the image). I also need that the column value should still increment by 8 at the beginning of the next row.** That is the column value should be 15X8+1=121 before the integer 16, after the integer 16 it should be 15X8+3=123, then cursor should jump to next row showing a column value of 16X8 + 1=129.

My code is below the image. (The column value for the cursor is shown at the bottom right in gedit or other text editors) [image]

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl
#include <iomanip>      // std::setw
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    
   FILE * fp;    
   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");

   int n=640;
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {
      fprintf(fp, "%-8d", i);
   }

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot "remove" the space when you have just printed it. It looks like you have to treat the printing of the last column specially.

Comment: Why use FILE and fprintf in C++ in the first place. These are left over things from backward compatibility with "C".  Use std::ifstream and if you have C++20 use std::format for your string formatting. (Any header file you include with a .h from C++ libraries is what I consider C legacy)

Comment: You can also "prepend" a space in all but the first iteration in your loop.
So : `if (i>1) print a space` that way you wont add spaces at the end.

Comment: Print the last column with `%d` only. The `-8` introduces the spaces. According to your program you are printing one row with 640 columns. The line break with the spaces before is probably actually due to your viewer. You can introduce `\n` for line breaks in between. Why is `640` not displayed? You have the condition `<= n` with `n = 640`

Comment: The column index is something your viewer determines. If you have line breaks, it should normally start with 1 again. If you do not have line breaks, it normally needs as many characters to increment the column number. It is the decision of your viewer to break long rows and whether to display spaces at the end of lines (but most/all viewers, which break overlong lines and show the column number, would). If you want to configure the viewer, it needs a programmable interface or it is off-topic for Stackoverflow. It probably won't be possible to get everything you want with modifying the file.

Comment: Perhaps using TABs instead of spaces between numbers and a viewer, which interprets TABs advantageously for your use case, would be most to your liking. I suggest trying to manually edit the file first (until it looks right in your viewer) and as a second step program to output it programmatically.

Comment: You could manually prefix each new value with enough spaces required to left-justify it on a tab-stop. Here's a naive way to do it by just tracking how many characters `fprintf` has written: https://godbolt.org/z/hEq9Tq6qW ... If it were me though, I would just blast my entire line of data into a string, then trim the trailing spaces from the end of it before writing it out.

Comment: Why not simply remove the `'-'` flag making your output *Left-Justified* and allow it to be *Right-Justified* in the 8-character field-width you specify?

Answer (score 0):

it is easy , you need add a judge.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl
#include <iomanip>      // std::setw
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    
   FILE * fp;    
   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");

   int n=640;
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {
      fprintf(fp, "%d ", i);  //fix printf
      if(i % 8 == 0){       //add a if judge
          fprintf(fp,"\n");   
      }
   }

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any space between the numbers...

Comment: hhh, it is a error. you are good !

Comment: But now you do have a blank before the line break. Isn't that OP's original problem?

Comment: The problem is that the OP wants incrementing text file column values by 8 per data column (so each column must have 8 characters width) and after explicit or implicit line breaks the column number should not start at 1 again.

Comment: @Sebastian this start 1 mean a thing  that per 8 second is a row. (1 <= 640) , 640  / 8 = 80 . it is right bro.  why should be start at 1??   because the thing " 0%8 ==0  " will be catch a error that one line will fprintf a '\n'

Comment: @j6t if you need read the file.    '\n' will be part the infos about per 8 elem.  if you need delete the '\n'  and keep one row have 8 elem...  I haven't some method.

Comment: @BingShanWang See the screenshot in the question. It counts lines and columns as starting with 1. So `(n % 8) + 1`